# Idiomatic way to return value from lambda in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, functional-programming

I have a function that returns some result and I am also measuring the running time of that function:

```
private suspend fun <T> runParallelTasksWithStatistics(
    chunksOfParallelTasks: List<List<T>>,
    task: suspend (SessionId?, ClientApiRpcProxy, T) -> Unit
): StressTestStatistics {
    val testStartTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val taskResults = runParallelTasks(chunksOfParallelTasks, task)
    val totalMillisPassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - testStartTimeMs

    return calculateStressTestStatistics(
        AggregateTaskResults(taskResults, totalMillisPassed)
    )
}
```

As you can see, after running the function `runParallelTasks(chunksOfParallelTasks, task)` I need two values:

1. `totalMillisPassed`
2. `taskResults`

How can I use `measureTimeMillis` without resorting to modifying `var` variable?

```
val totalMillisPassed = measureTimeMillis {
    val taskResults = runParallelTasks(chunksOfParallelTasks, task)
}

AggregateTaskResults(taskResults, totalMillisPassed)
```

At the scope of `AggregateTaskResults()` I only see `totalMillisPassed`, but I also want to access the result `taskResults`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your own version of `measureTimeMilis` that returns the time *and* a result:

```
fun <R> measureTimeMillisWithResult(block: () -> R): Pair<Long, R> {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = block()
    return Pair(System.currentTimeMillis() - start, result)
}
```

And to call it, you can take advantage of the fact that `Pair` can be destructured:

```
val (time, result) = measureTimeMillisWithResult {
    // Calculate the result here.
}
println("Calculation took $time ms")
return result
```

Comment: Hmm, so there is no standard Kotlin method that allows to do that?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Todds answer, but still implementing your own function:

```
inline fun <T> measureTimeMillis(handleDuration: (Long) -> Unit = { }, supplier: () -> T): T {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    return supplier().also {
        handleDuration(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)
    }
}
```

Usage then looks as follows:

```
val result = measureTimeMillis {
   // your function
}
```

or if you want to do something else with the duration:

```
val result = measureTimeMillis(::registerDuration) {
   // your function
}
val result = measureTimeMillis( { println("Took $it ms") } ) {
   // your function
}
```

So that you do not get confused with the standard function another name is probably helpful.

I created my own measure wrapper type for this, so that I'm easily able to enhance some expressions with my default measurer (that logs or prints or whatever). If I want to measure something I just add `measurer measure` (used an `infix` for it) in front of a line or before an assignment, so that there is no need to handle the returned milliseconds per measurement.